# Java VM Best choice for windows CE

Tags: java, windows-ce, midp

What is, currently, the best choice to run MIDP applets in a Windows CE based System?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use IBM's J9 JVM on Win CE.  You don't have to be an IBM ISV Partner to get it.  You can buy it from IBM partners like the one we use.  Here is a link to Microdoc's site showing the platforms where the J9 JVM is available.  http://www.microdoc.com/products/certified-me-runtimes.  We've been very happy with J9.

Comment: J9 is definitely the way to go. You can use rapitools in your ant builds to speed up development. You can even use the cab wizard for some really cool deployment scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the ONLY choice available to you is [SuperWaba/TotalCross](http://www.superwaba.com.br/en/tc_overview.asp).

WebSphere Micro Edition might also be available to you if you're an IBM ISV Partner.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience IBM's J9 is the best - I've used it to support MIDP/CDC apps, but the profile/configuration combinations supported include MIDP and Personal Profile, and both CLDC and CDC Foundation.

In contrast to other opinions, there is not a single choice of VM if you Google around. But I went for J9 because it proports to follow proper Java compatibility, **unlike** SuperWaba that is basically a Java variant so your 'Java' apps would be less portable.