# How to install an application into the Windows CE 7 image?

Tags: java, installation, windows-ce, android-sdk-2.3

I was looking for a guideline on how to install or better said how to integrate an application into the Windows CE 7 run-time image.

Concretely I need to install Android SDK into the Win CE 7 Image.
If it is not possible then does anybody can say if is it possible to install it after
first boot. The same question can be applied on Java JRE for embedded devices.
In my situation I have ARM 7 based board with enough resources to run Win CE 7.
In fact I managed to install it. Now I need Java on it.

This question can be easily extended on other applications. It is always simple to install
something you made and know what registry entries, drivers and other applications you
need for running but in case of third party you have to ask or try it yourself.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Windows CE is not the same as normal ("desktop") Windows. There doesn't appear to be a JRE freely available for Windows CE, so the Android SDK is definitely not available.

Comment: I know about the JRE but still know that exists the Java ME for mobile and embedded OS. The main problem is to find a correct Java JVM for ARM 7 not x86. About the Android SDK I know very little so don't know if it relies on the same Java like used on standalon PCs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JVM choices on Windows Mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55322/jvm-choices-on-windows-mobile)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your questions is vague or broad.  I'm not sure which.

If you want to know how to integrate some application or DLL with the platform, then there's a general methodology of using REG/BIB and DAT files.  This works for your own app of third party apps.  It's how *any* file is put into the OS image, Java or otherwise.  That's covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9394882/add-cab-file-to-the-os-design) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636508/how-can-i-load-third-party-dll-com-dll-in-atl-application-with-wince-5-0-rtos)

If you're asking about a JVM for CE, that's a completely different question, already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55322/jvm-choices-on-windows-mobile), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882732/is-it-possible-to-run-java-programs-on-windows-ce), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514252/java-vm-best-choice-for-windows-ce), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517906/java-me-on-windows-mobile).

Now when you talk about "SDK", which is "software developer's kit", it nearly sounds like you want to *develop* android apps on your CE device. That's somewhat asked (and not properly answered) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161640/compiler-for-windows-mobile-os), but the answer is pretty much "there really isn't a tool for it and why would you do tyhis anyway?"

Comment: I am aware of bib, dat and reg files. I do not need informations about that. I am asking on behalf of my client who already started developing a java application and wants to run it on Windows CE 7. I already built the OS image but now want try to add the JVM. When JVM is installed on x86 everything is made by automatic installation so I dont't know if or how is it possible to install it on non x86 like ARM. I am aware of some special Java versions targeted for mobile PC based on ARM. About the Android SDK don't worry. It is again a request from the client.

Comment: So the question is much better written as "How do I run a Java application on Windows CE", not "How to install an application in a Windows CE image" and that question has been asked here on SO before (see the links above).

Comment: Yes but I am not satisfied with the responses found here. So I asked more general question to try to find a solution myself using ideas of others.